# prove that 2 collection have the same VC-dimensions

Tags: functions, computer-science, boolean-algebra, machine-learning

I'm new here on the site, I'm a final year student in computer science.
In a machine learning course, there was a question on a test that I could not understand.

The question goes like this:

Suppose that $ F\subseteq\{0,1\}^\Omega $ is some collection of Boolean functions over $\Omega $.

Define $\Omega'=\Omega\times\{0,1\}$ and define $F'$ to be the collection of Boolean functions over $\Omega$ as follows:

for every $f\in F$, there is some $f'\in F'$ that maps $(x,y)\in\Omega'$ to $1[f(x)\neq y]$. (Furthermore, $F'$ consists only of such $f'$; no other functions are allowed.) Prove that the VC-dimensions of $F$ and $F'$
are equal.

What I was able to understand is that there is a collection of some functions $F$, and that all these functions with the addition of $0$ and $1$ are also in $F '$

I think $F '$is like $F$ only if an addition of $0$ and $1$ to the functions.

Can't figure out how to prove it.

Comment: Sorry for the comment that I just deleted, I realized after reading the bounty text that you do not understand what the VC dimension is. That is very crucial to this question, however. Would you mind conversing a little with me so I can understand your background? I would like to start with the following question, which I ask a bit honestly : there are many notations used here, that you seem to be unfamiliar with. Do you have some kind of class notes to share, because I have no clue how so many of the definitions in class can be used in the final exam without being spoken of in class.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4282475/14578, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/144960/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).